# Function integrating besselk function

Tags: vba, parameters, double

I am trying to create a function that has the BESSELK function as a parameter. I found this code on fordom.free.fr :

```
Option Explicit

Function F(ByVal Equation As String, Optional ByVal X As Variant = 0) As Double
'Evaluates f(x) at position x

'Uppercase
Equation = UCase(Equation)
With WorksheetFunction
'avoid mixing up EXP with exp and X
Equation = .Substitute(Equation, "EXP", "exp")
'set value X instead of letter X
Equation = .Substitute(Equation, "X", X)
'converts comas into points
Equation = .Substitute(Equation, ",", ".")
'Changes )( with )*(
Equation = .Substitute(Equation, ")(", ")*(")
End With

'calculates expression
F = Evaluate(Equation)

End Function
```

And modified it to take into account 2 parameters :

```
Option Explicit

Function F(ByVal Equation As String, Optional ByVal X As Variant = 0, _
& **Optional ByVal Y As Variant = 0**) As Double
'Evaluates f(x) at position x

'Uppercase
Equation = UCase(Equation)
With WorksheetFunction
'avoid mixing up EXP with exp and X
Equation = .Substitute(Equation, "EXP", "exp")
'set value X instead of letter X
Equation = .Substitute(Equation, "X", X)
**'set value Y instead of letter Y
Equation = .Substitute(Equation, "Y", Y)**
'converts comas into points
Equation = .Substitute(Equation, ",", ".")
'Changes )( with )*(
Equation = .Substitute(Equation, ")(", ")*(")
End With

'calculates expression
F = Evaluate(Equation)

End Function
```

When I try F("x+y";5;2), it returns 7 which is alright. However, when i try
F("BESSELK(x;y)";5;1), it gives me a #VALUE error

I checked in the documentation and the variable type or the two arguments from the Bessel function are indeed "Variante".

I don't really understand why it going wrong here ! I also tried with an easier function F("POWER(x;y)";5;2) but it also give me a #VALUE error.

Any help is more than welcome ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of these lines

> `Equation = .Substitute(Equation, "EXP", "exp")`
>
> `Equation = .Substitute(Equation, "Y", Y)`

is that the formal parameters `X` and `Y` should be written in **uppercase** inside the formula.

```
=F("BESSELK(X;Y)";5;1) ' <-- Capital X, capital Y
=F("POWER(x;y)";5;2)   ' <-- idem
```

Note that this UDF works only with your locale settings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to set the variable inside the BESSELK function with capital letters, but it did not change anything, there is still the  #VALUE error. It feels like the parameters X and Y are not linked to the BESSELK function.

Comment: No your  code worked for me after I changed it for my locale (removed the line `Equation = .Substitute(Equation, ",", ".")` and used commas instead of semi-colons in the formula). BESSELK should work as well. What is your locale setting?

Comment: Did you try `=F("POWER(x;y)";5;2)` ?